# Regex for accepting only Paranthesis in input

Tags: java, regex, complex-numbers

i want to write a Regex expression to accept only "(", ")","{","}","[","]" these values in input, anything other then this should be invalid input. Here's my code:

````
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regex = "^.*[\\(\\)\\{\\}\\[\\]].*$";
          //Reading input from user
          Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Enter data: ");
          String input = sc.nextLine();
          //Instantiating the Pattern class
          Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
          //Instantiating the Matcher class
          Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
          //verifying whether a match occurred
          if(matcher.find()) {
             System.out.println("Input accepted");
          }else {
             System.out.println("Not accepted");
            }
        }
    }```

I also tried String regex = "^.[\\(\\)\\{\\}\\[\\]]*.$", it doesn't work.

{(}){(}) - Valid input
P{())}}() - invalid input
12{}() - invalid input
.;/{{}) - invalid input
{}}} - valid input
````

Comment: You've got `.*` at both the start and end. That means you'll accept *any* string that contains one of those characters somewhere in the string. Why do you have `.*` at all?

Comment: Yup this worked, removed the .* and now it only accepts the paranthessis now.. first it would accept any letter number or character before or after or anywhere in the input..

Comment: however only removing this didn't work, i had to use + at the end. as one of the answers suggested below this worked perfectly ---> "^[\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}]+$";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all of them `(`, `)`,`{`,`}`,`[`,`]` are special character in `regex`,you need to escape them by using `\` in regex expresssion,  in order to archinve your golal, we can use `^[\(\)\[\]\{\}]+$` to do it

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/rb4BHM/1)

In java,the expression is as below:

```
String regex ="^[\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}]+$";
```

Comment: this works the way it should.. not accepting anything if input has anything else other then paranthessis.. Perfect, now how to restrict its length, like it shouldn't be longer then 104 character, how to restrict it using regex

Comment: @MustafaInayat: Please don't use comments to ask further questions. Instead, do the research (the docs for Pattern are a good starting point) and ask a new question if you really need to.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Java doesn't use `/`s to represent regex. So the fix would be:

```
String regex = "^[\{\}\(\)\[\]]*$";
// The rest of the code
```

**Original Answer**

Try using this `/^[\{\}\(\)\[\]]*$/`

Comment: Java does not use `/` to represent regexes.

Comment: Mentioning that only the square brackets need escaping (actually just the closing one here). Why? Because they are inside square brackets (character class).

Comment: using only \ this gives an error, i think it is used for indentations in output. hence i had to use \\ this, syntaxually its fine. but the input accepting criteria is not working